# WebApp: suggestion about how save a lot of information from a Sphinx search

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat7, lazy-loading, sphinx

I have an issue about my webapp: it's a intranet search webapp that asks Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/ (the real search engine) for a query typed by the user. The problem is that the result could be very big (also for a intranet network) so I want to save the result on the server to handle a sort of lazy load of the data.

I suppose to use Hibernate but...if the result is too big and I save, for example, 40.000 items...will it be too effort for hibernate? And retrieving them?!

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a limit and offset in the sphinxsearch itself: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.3/api-func-setlimits.html. As from this doc a word about limiting the result from the sphinx server (which is 1000 by default):

> One thousand records is enough to present to the end user. And if you're thinking about pulling the results to application for further sorting or filtering, that would be much more efficient if performed on Sphinx side.

Comment: I can't limit the result. It's a feature search and extract all those items

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve. Lazy loading should be possible to do at the sphinx side in exactly the same manner as on your server.

Comment: The problem is to send all these result to the user browser. When the user searches something, results are aggregated into categories of object. So the user can click on one category and see all the results of the category with a set of attributes. Clicking on a single result, the user can see all the details of the result (all attributes).
The lazy loading is mandatory because a single category could contain 1000 results.

Comment: Ok, I would still let sphinx do all the lazy loading stuff. So first query to sphinx would just be a category query (group by category, you can get the counts etc). When a user clicks a category, do a more specific sphinx query. This query then can optionally be paged with limit/offset. When a single result is clicked, do yet another (sphinx) query to get the results. Performance would benefit from this as well, as there is less work to do, and less data to be passed around (the user will not see most of the data, so it's a waste to fetch it before)

Comment: Yes, but it's not so simple. Each category has a set of attributes listed in a properties file. Sphinx doesn't know categories because they are aggregated by the webapp. And how they are aggregated is not linear. So when the user clicks on a category to start a more detailed search to show, in my opinion, the webapp should redo the first query and filter results later...but I think it could be so heavy. But maybe it's the only solution: any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't it possible to move the categories to sphinx then? That would be the most simple solution. We have a constant changing dataset of over 1,500,000,000 documents in our database. For searching we just rebuilt and rotate a sphinx index a few times a day. So people may find older data in the index but it's a tradeoff for speed. It depends really on what is acceptable in your environmant.

Comment: You are right...I was bound at this idea to be more flexible with properties but this is the best solution to not go mad :-) . Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem :) If you want live changing properties in the index, you might want to look into realtime index updates. At least for attirbutes this should not be too complicated I think.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm missing something, but why not just get it piecemeal direct out of sphinx? You can jsut get small pages worth of results at a time. with setLimits.

That way you dont download the data as you need it.

Comment: I can't limit the result. It's a feature search and extract all those items. The webapp searches over three index of sphinx and each index has as limit 20k. So the user could retrieve 60k of results: it's rare...but it could be.

Comment: Why don't you let sphinx combine them all into one resultset? It does that too.

Comment: Because each single index works with a single type of object quite different from the others. Any type of object contains about 20-30 attributes. If I merge all the types I will obtain a confused configuration and too many empty attributes. And so the result won't change because Sphinx has to retrieve anyway about 60k results